# Symfony set block content from controller

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Is there a way to set a template block content from within a controller in Symfony?

Is there a way to do something like this from within a controller?

```
$this->get('templating')->setBlockContent('page_title', $page_title);
```

I need to set the page title dynamically and I want to avoid modifying every single action template.

I know I can pass the `$page_title` variable to `Controller:render` but I don't want to add

```
{% block title %}
{{ page_title }}
{% endblock %}
```

to every single action template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since any parent Twig templates handle variables that are passed to their children templates, there's a simpler method to achieve what you want to do. In fact, this method is the basic equivalent of writing content into an entire block from the controller since we're essentially just inserting a passed `render` variable directly into the contents using `{% block %}{{ variable }}{% endblock %}`

#### Start a base layout template with the title block

```
{# Resources/views/base.html.twig #}
<html>
<head>
     <title>{% block title %}{{ page_title is defined ? page_title }}{% endblock %}</title>
{# ... Rest of your HTML base template #}
</html>
```

The `{% block %}` part is not necessary but useful if you ever want to override or append to it (using `parent()`)

You can also add a site-wide title so the `page_title` can be appended if it exists:

```
<title>{% block title %}{{ page_title is defined ? page_title ~ ' | ' }}Acme Industries Inc.{% endblock %}</title>
```

#### Extend this base layout with every child template

```
{# Resources/views/Child/template.html.twig #}
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{# You can even re-use the page_title for things like heading tags #}
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ page_title }}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

#### Pass the `page_title` into your `render` function which references your child template

```
return $this->render('AcmeBundle:Child:template.html.twig', array(
    'page_title' => 'Title goes here!',
));
```