# Is there a way, to change a block of a twig template within a controller (php file)

Tags: php, twig

Let's say I have the following twig templates:

```
{% block header %}My header{% endblock %}
{% block middle %}My middle{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}My footer{% endblock %}
```

In my controller, I render the twig file (with laravel twig bridge, but it would be similar in other frameworks):

```php
public function index() {
   $view = view('template.twig');

   return $view->render();
}
```

So is there a way, to manipulate the `$view` to set for example the block `middle` to `My new middle`, within the controller, without touching the `template.twig` file?

I know, I could create a new `child.twig` where I do

```
{% extends "template" %}

{% block middle %}My new middle{% endblock}
```

but is there a way to do it, without an extra twig file directly form the controller? Something like

```php
$view->setBlock('middle', 'My new middle');
```

Comment: Perhaps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178919/symfony-set-block-content-from-controller ?

Comment: That would be a way around, but not exactly what I want, since I would need to add these variables to all twig files. Basically I would have to write something like this `{% block middle %}{%if block_middle is defined %}{{ block_middle }}{% else %}My middle{% endif %}{% endblock}` on every block.

Comment: dunno if it would be a good idea, would mean u couldn't benefit from cached twig templates anymore as well

Comment: @bernhardh that's the complex way, use the [`default`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/default.html) filter rather: `{{ block_middle | default('My middle') }}`